# Find Python module filename

Tags: python, python-2.7

I got module name which contains declaration of `os.path.isfile`. [Jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi) lib gave me `genericpath` (without file path). Now i want to get full filename of PY file with this `genericpath` module. E.g. "C:\Py27\Lib\genericpath.py". How can I do it? Jedi cannot do it?

Comment: `print(genericpath)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could check the value of `__file__`:

```
>>> import genericpath
>>> genericpath.__file__
 '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/genericpath.pyc'
```

Comment: Yes, the source code is in the .py file. The .pyc contains a "compiled" version of the code

Comment: What if pyc file is not accompanied by py file?

Answer (score 13):

When `__file__` doesn't work, do it the proper way—use [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html):

```
>>> import somemodule
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getfile(somemodule)
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/somemodule.pyc'
```

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.7/re.pyc'
```

For packages that are not part of the Python core, you can also use `__path__`:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.__file__
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/requests/__init__.pyc'
>>> requests.__path__
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/requests']
```

Comment: Note, ``__path__`` is unreliable because it can be changed at runtime. It is really meant to be a search path and not a location. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages-in-multiple-directories

Answer (score 0):

Get module filename without loading it:

```py
print(importlib.util.find_spec("urllib.request", None).origin)
```